# Using spark components in a .fla

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to use Spark components in a Flash Professional CC project. I've added AIR 14 to Flash CC:

[image]

and I've adjust my preferences to use Apache Flex SDK and pointed it to paths of Flex additional libraries:

[image]

Now, I can add spark components to my project:

```
import spark.components.Button;

var btn:Button = new Button();  
btn.label = "Test";  
btn.x = 300;  
btn.y = 300;  
this.addChild(btn);
```

but when I run it, it doesn't show them. What it's wrong?

PD: Sorry about my poor English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark components cannot be used in a Flash CC project. Those components are meant to be initialized by a Flex system of managers (style, css, etc) and never directly created by the coder himself. They can only work within a mxml based project where initialization of components is deferred and handled by those managers. In fewer words, spark components have been made to work exclusively in Flex based projects and there's no direct way to use them in Flash projects.

Comment: Could I compile a swf with Flex (with Spark components embedded in it) and use it into a Flash CC project?

Comment: Yes this is the only known workaround but it is not very reliable since instantiation of components inside that loaded swf can fail because the swf does not own the stage and Flex managers expect to own it. You'll need to write additional check and init methods to make sure your components have been created normally. It is not an easy road.

Comment: Thanks! I afraid I'll have to rewrite my nice Skin in a old fashionable Flash style for my coworkers. Sorry, I haven't enough reputation points for vote up for you answer